# How to trick web browser about Range Requests?

Tags: apache-2.2, http

I'm using Apache HTTP server 2.2 with ubuntu 12.04 (with mod_rewrite & mod_headers )
I've changed server config to

```
MaxRanges none
```

So now when Web browser hits server he receives answer

```
Accept-Ranges: none
```

How to trick web browser that he still can ask for range request ? e.g.

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

thanks ;)

Comment: Why would you disable a thing then attempt to make it seem there ?

Comment: I'm developing client-side software for video playback. I want test every possible scenario. For example, if you play mp4 video from dropbox, their server will return you that he can do range requests, but actually he don't

Answer (score 0):

Write your own web server that blatantly ignores the standards, lies about its capabilities, and returns `HTTP/400` ("Bad Request"), or if you want to be really confusing `HTTP/406` ("Not Acceptable" - even though you *you just bloody well said it was acceptable*).

Seriously, that's the only way this is going to happen. You're trying to create a situation that *can't exist*. Testing this corner case is admirable, but you're going to have to hack it together yourself.